# How can I really understand the method of 'Array.prototype.join'

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I use the method of `Array.prototype.join` for multidimensional array, but I get curious result. I try to see the bottom implementation of `Array.prototype.join`, it show me the native code

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8].join('')
[1, [2], [3, [4, [5]]], [6, [7, [8]]]].join('');
```

I expect the output of

```
[1,[2],[3,[4,[5]]],[6,[7,[8]]]].join('')
```

to be

12345678

but the actual output is

123,4,56,7,8

Comment: the output of  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8].join('')  is be ''12345678"

Comment: I only want to know why the output of [1,[2],[3,[4,[5]]],[6,[7,[8]]]].join('') is be "123,4, 56,7,8", and how do the method work?

Comment: [The standard](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.joinhttps://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.join) is a good resource for finding a detailed answer what an internal method does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.join` calls `.toString()` on each element to turn it into a string, and `Array.prototype.toString()` by default concatenates all its elements with a `,`.

```js
console.log([1, 2, 3].toString());
```

Comment: No. I  only want to know why the output of [1,[2],[3,[4,[5]]],[6,[7,[8]]]].join('') is be "123,4, 56,7,8", and how do the method work?

Comment: I explained it. Read it again slowly and go through the process with pen and paper if necessary.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't understand.  [1, [2], [3, [4, [5]]], [6, [7, [8]]]].toString() will be "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8",  but [1,[2],[3,[4,[5]]],[6,[7,[8]]]].join('') will be "123,4,56,7,8" . They are different.

Comment: If you do `join('')`, all items of the array will be joined by `''` (i.e, no visible separator). However, every item in your array *that is an array* will be converted using `.toString`, so the `[3, [4, [5]]]` inside your array will turn into the string `"3,4,5"` (which is `[5]` converted to `"5"`, and `[4, "5"]`  converted to `"4,5"`, and `[3, "4,5"]` converted to `"3,4,5"`), which is then joined to the rest with `''`.

Comment: Why would it be `1,2,3...`? `[2].toString()` turns into just `"2"`, which is joined to `1` with `''`, giving `"12"`!

Comment: This may be easier if you use `.join('|')`: `"1|2|3,4,5|6,7,8"`. `join` inserts the `|`, and the implicit `toString` inserts the `,`.

Answer (score 2):

Like others already said, *toString* is called upon the array. However, by providing a separator it will only join the array on which you call the method with that separator.

```
[
  1, 
  [2], 
  [3, [4, [5]]], 
  [6, [7, [8]]]
].join("")
```

Will simply join the first level elements together, calling *toString* on elements that aren't a string.

```
1.toString() + "" +
 [2].toString() + "" +
 [3, [4, [5]]].toString() + "" +
 [6, [7, [8]]].toString()
```

Where the `""` is the separator. Resulting in `123,4,56,7,8` where `3,4,5` is the first nested array and `6,7,8` the second (with more than 1 element). If you'd like to join the elements recursive you could create your own method.

```js
Array.prototype.deepJoin = function (separator) {
  return this
    .map(e => Array.isArray(e) ? e.deepJoin(separator) : e)
    .join(separator);
};

var array = [1, [2], [3, [4, [5]]], [6, [7, [8]]]];

console.log(array.join());
console.log(array.deepJoin());
console.log(array.join(""));
console.log(array.deepJoin(""));
console.log(array.join(" - "));
console.log(array.deepJoin(" - "));
```

Answer (score 1):

The `join` method also invoke `toString()` on each element.

You have

```
[2].toString() -> 2
[3, [4, 5]].toString() -> 3,4,5
```

And so on. The `toString` method on an array *never* preserves square parenthesis